# Ask users for feedback and permission to contact them

Tags: user-behavior, contact-us

I might be overthinking this.

We have an app that doesn't have user profiles. We would like to ask for feedback from our users by asking for them to for contact details?

Is this a smart way to go about it?

If we just give them our email - how likely they would respond to it? Is it better to ask them for their contact details?

I am afraid that forms/questionnaires are just to clunky for user to use (I personally would never fill them in) and will not capture the essence of the user interview, ie. we would love to talk to people and learn what leads them to repeat use of the app.

And if we do ask for their details how does this sound?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Copy sounds nice. Warm and inviting. I am not sure about you, but I can’t stand those horrible squares with curved borders that sit bottom right of the screen. Try and make sure that your ‘pop up’ modal doesn’t ruin the awesome experience you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for feedback David. not sure what you mean curved border that sit *bottom right* ? This was a cropped screen-shot.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the button that activates this. I take it this modal is not visible at all times?

Comment: There is no button that activates it. We display it when app is opened (where certain condition of app usage has been met, eg specific amount of conversion events have been reached).

Answer (score 2):

So your goal is to get feedback?
You should remove every impediment possible for the user.

That means users should have the ability to enter their feedback right then and there, because thats mostly when frustration happens and they are eager to tell you.

People don't like to enter their information anywhere and even less if they don't gain something from it, a newsletter for example makes the user gain something for entering his e-mail.

[image]

[image]

Just modified your example a little bit.

Comment: @PM Firstly thanks for sending a modification! You are absolutely right about asking the feedback at the pain point - I forgot about that one :) 
What I really need is to find out is what leads people to open our app and how/why they use it? That is the main reason I was going for direct contact. - Do you think the form like this would be sufficient? Or should we ask for email after they give feedback (maybe with incentive).

Comment: You can provide the question with a set of options to answer, that makes it easier for the user since you save him the writing part, of course to provide decent answer-options you need to know the most popular use cases. You can do this with a combobox for example. What you can add in the end is something like "Can we contact you regarding your feedback?" which then gives the user the option to enter his e-mail address and/or phone.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for phone number could lead to problems of calling at the wrong time and trying to set a time to talk. Literally everybody is busy. Email also has pros and cons, it might go to spam, but could also sit on their email until they are ready to collaborate.

However, if you want to get conversions, offer a small incentive and followup with a screener survey through email. Interview whoever passed your screener and seems fit for your questions. You'll get chance to get both quantitative and qualitative feedback this way.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, my view was to ask users to send any type of  'contact detail' they feel comfortable with. Then I'd engage in convo. There is a risk of them not responding to an email, but i feel this is least friction for the user.

Do you suggest we offer incentive right away on this screen? Or later in the email. This makes sense too me for users I'd identify as core through their usage.

Comment: Hey Milan, it depends on the quality of responses. Not putting the incentive will naturally lead to only proactive users and those who case most about your product to contact, since no reward is suggested. While putting an incentive might just lead to a an outpour or contacts and might give you a headache screening them. But maybe I'm wrong, you could try both ways and see if it affects the quality of respondents.